# Why divide $R$ by heat capacity and not the other way around?

Tags: thermodynamics

> $$ C_V dT+RT \frac{dV}{V}=0$$
>   Let us transform the above expression as follows:
>   $$\frac{dT}{T} + \frac{R}{C_V}\frac{dV}{V} = 0$$
>   This expression can be written in the form
>   $$ d\left( \ln T + \frac{R}{C_V}\ln V\right)=0$$
>   whence it follows that in an adiabatic process
>   $$\ln T + \frac{R}{C_V}\ln V = \rm const \tag{10.40}$$
>   In accordance with Eq. (10.35), the ratio $R/C_V$ can be replaced with $\gamma-1$, where $\gamma = C_p/C_V$. Making this substitution in Eq. (10.40) and converting to a power, we get
>   $$ TV^{\gamma-1} = \rm const \tag{10.41}$$

My question  is why divide $R$ by $C_v$ and why not the other way around. I mean dividing $C_v$ by $R$. It should lead to a different answer?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable by all users and so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead. In addition, we expect all quotes to be suitably attributed to their source.

Comment: Can you think of a single example where you use two different methods to solve an equation and the answers come out different?

Answer (score 3):

If you did that, then you'd get an equivalent equation in a slightly different form, i.e.

$$\frac{C_V}{R}\ln T + \ln V = \rm const \tag{10.40'}$$

and therefore

$$ T^{\frac{1}{\gamma-1}}V = \rm const. \tag{10.41'}$$

This is correct, but it is slightly less pretty because of the fraction in the exponent, which is why we normally do things the way the book does, to end up in the form $TV^{\gamma-1}$, which is easier to write.

You cannot get different answers (as in, *actually* different, not just re-dressings of the same fact) by performing correct and information-preserving steps on the same starting point.

Comment: so both are correct?